# Can Not View Content Blocks due to require.js error - Magento 2 theme change

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I am facing problem with `require.js` on Magento 2 theme change 
**Content > Blocks**
The page shows endless spinner and I can never view my imported blocks for my new theme. When I do Firebug on the page. This is the error message

> Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes
>   htt://requirejs.org/docs/errorshtml#scripterror require.js (line 166,
>   col 17)
>
> Error: Script error for: Magento_AdminNotification/toolbar_entry
>   htt://requirejs.org/docs/errorshtml#scripterror require.js (line 166,
>   col 17)
>
> Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/core/app
>   htt://requirejs.org/docs/errorshtml#scripterror require.js (line 166,
>   col 17)
>
> Error: Script error for: Magento_AdminNotification/system/notification
>   htt://requirejs.org/docs/errorshtml#scripterror require.js (line 166,
>   col 17)

Can someone help me resolving this require.js issue?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: the missing p in http in all resources is quite flashy, althouth I'm not sure what could cause this

Answer (score 0):

First of all your link have `missing p in htt::// instead of http://`. so check about url issue.
If further issue is not resolve, try cmd command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

remove var folder from root.

Also set permission for magento projects.

Comment: Hi Rakesh , the missing p is because when I try to copy paste to this forum , i got a warning message of url .that's why I remove the p.  I have removed var from root but now my backend has broken style. I also have set file permission to 644 and directory to 755. Previously, I have set  file permission to 660 and directory to 770, but still has the same loading spinner problem. Is there another way ?

Comment: Run php bin/Magento setup:di:compile and then php bin/Magento setup:static-content :deploy and finally cache:clean and try once

Comment: @rakesh please look in to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298598/inventory-management-based-on-customer-group